# Documenting Scala 2.10 macros

Tags: scala, macros, documentation, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I'll start with an example. Here's an equivalent of `List.fill` for tuples as a macro in Scala 2.10:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object TupleExample {
  def fill[A](arity: Int)(a: A): Product = macro fill_impl[A]

  def fill_impl[A](c: Context)(arity: c.Expr[Int])(a: c.Expr[A]) = {
    import c.universe._

    arity.tree match {
      case Literal(Constant(n: Int)) if n < 23 => c.Expr(
        Apply(
          Select(Ident("Tuple" + n.toString), "apply"),
          List.fill(n)(a.tree)
        )
      )
      case _ => c.abort(
        c.enclosingPosition,
        "Desired arity must be a compile-time constant less than 23!"
      )
    }
  }
}
```

We can use this method as follows:

```
scala> TupleExample.fill(3)("hello")
res0: (String, String, String) = (hello,hello,hello)
```

This guy is a weird bird in a couple of respects. First, the `arity` argument must be a literal integer, since we need to use it at compile time. In previous versions of Scala there was no way (as far as I know) for a method even to tell whether one of its arguments was a compile-time literal or not.

Second, the `Product` return type [is a lie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673950/334519)—the static return type will include the specific arity and element type determined by the arguments, as shown above.

So how would I document this thing? I'm not expecting Scaladoc support at this point, but I'd like to have a sense of conventions or best practices (beyond just making sure the compile-time error messages are clear) that would make running into a macro method—with its potentially bizarre demands—less surprising for users of a Scala 2.10 library.

The most mature demonstrations of the new macro system (e.g., [ScalaMock](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock), [Slick](https://github.com/slick/slick), the others listed [here](http://scalamacros.org/news/2012/11/05/status-update.html)) are still relatively undocumented at the method level. Any examples or pointers would be appreciated, including ones from other languages with similar macro systems.

Comment: Regarding ScalaMock, as the author, I'd be very grateful for suggestions about how I could improve the documentation. ScalaMock is effectively a DSL, so documenting individual methods doesn't necessarily mean much. I've tried to document the DSL as a whole here: http://scalamock.org/api/index.html#org.scalamock.package and there's getting started documentation here: http://www.paulbutcher.com/2012/10/scalamock3-step-by-step/ What could I add that would help?

Comment: @PaulButcher: I don't mean to criticize ScalaMock, and I've edited the answer to make that clearer. I've found reading your code extremely useful as I've been trying to understand Scala's macros, and I think the high-level documentation is very clear.

Comment: No offence taken. But I would definitely appreciate any and all suggestions for ways in which I could make improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to document these is with example code, as Miles has been doing in his experimental [macro based branch](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/topic/macro-paradise/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/monoids.scala) of shapeless.