# Scala Macro: Define Top Level Object

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I looked `type macros` for scala. But when i would like create object from example, i got error:

```
Example.scala:7: `=', `>:', or `<:' expected
type Test(url: String) = macro impl

Example.scala:12: illegal start of simple expression
val clazz = ClassDef(..., Template(..., generateCode()))
```

Code:

```
//Example.sbt
object Example {

  type Test(url: String) = macro impl

  def impl(c:Context)(url: c.Expr[String]):c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val name = c.freshName(c.enclosingImpl.name).toTypeName
    val clazz = ClassDef(..., Template(..., generateCode()))
    c.introduceTopLevel(c.enclosingPackage.pid.toString, clazz)
    val classRef = Select(c.enclosingPackage.pid, name)
    Apply(classRef, List(Literal(Constant(c.eval(url)))))
  }
}
```

Scala version: 2.10.2

From: [type macros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/typemacros.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only it were that easy! From [the documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/typemacros.html) you link to:

> Type macros are a pre-release feature included in so-called macro
>   paradise, an experimental branch in the official Scala repository.
>   Follow the instructions at the "Macro Paradise" page to download and
>   use our nightly builds.

And:

> Please note that due to binary compatibility restrictions, macro
>   paradise for 2.10.x doesn't include any features from macro paradise
>   2.11.x except for quasiquotes.

So you're going to have to move to the [Macro Paradise](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) branch for 2.11 if you want this to work.

Note also that the `...` in the type macros documentation is intended to indicate elided code—you can't just copy and paste it.

Comment: thanks. But is there another way to generate class definitions?

Comment: In 2.10? Kind of. You can generate an anonymous class instance with arbitrarily-named members and it'll have an inferred structural type that includes those members. See [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13669974/334519) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14370842/334519) or [my blog post here](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/19/macro-supported-dsls-for-schema-bindings/) for some examples.

Comment: Thanks Travis for the replies.