# How to generate top-level class/object with scala macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

As we know, it is easy to create an inner class in some methods with scala macro. 
But I'd like to know is it possible to generate a top level class/object?
If the answer is yes, then how to avoid generate the same class twice?
my scala version is 2.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 5. **Top-level** expansions must retain the number of annottees, their flavors and their names, with the only exception that a class might expand into a same-named class plus a same-named module, in which case they automatically become companions as per previous rule.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html

So you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048310/automatically-generate-case-object-for-case-class/) transform top-level

```
@annot
class A
```

into

```
class A
object A
```

or

```
@annot
object A
```

into

```
class A
object A
```

Also there existed `c.introduceTopLevel` but it was removed.

> 21. `Context.introduceTopLevel`. The `Context.introduceTopLevel` API, which used to be available in early milestone builds of Scala 2.11.0 as a stepping stone towards type macros, was removed from the final release, because type macros were rejected for including in Scala and discontinued in macro paradise.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/changelog211.html

[Scala Macro: Define Top Level Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326661/scala-macro-define-top-level-object)

> `introduceTopLevel` has provided a long-requested functionality of generating definitions that can be used outside macro expansions. However, metaprogrammers have
>   quickly discovered that `introduceTopLevel` is dangerous. Top-level scope is a resource shared between the typechecker and user metaprograms, so mutating it with
>   `introduceTopLevel` can lead to compilation order problems. For example, if one file
>   in a compilation run relies on definitions created by a macro expansion performed in
>   another file, compiling the former before the latter may lead to unexpected compilation
>   errors.

https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/226166/files/EPFL_TH7159.pdf (section 5.2.3 Conclusion)

If the companion you want to generate already exists then the companion you return in macro annotation's `macroTransform` will replace the original. You don't need to beware that there will be two "companions", compiler will watch that. But surely normally you match if that's the case (whether there is only annottee or annottee + companion).