# Play Framework - add a field to JSON object

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a problem with adding a field to Json object in Play Framework using Scala:

I have a case class containing data. For example:

```
case class ClassA(a:Int,b:Int)
```

and I am able to create a Json object using Json Writes:

```
val classAObject = ClassA(1,2)
implicit val classAWrites= Json.writes[ClassA]
val jsonObject = Json.toJson(classAObject)
```

and the Json would look like:

```
{ a:1, b:2 }
```

Let's suppose I would like to add an additional 'c' field to the Json object. Result:

```
{ a:1, b:2, c:3 }
```

How do I do that without creating a new case class or creating my Json object myself using Json.obj? I am looking for something like:

```
jsonObject.merge({c:3})
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`JsObject` has a `+` method that allows you to add fields to an object, but unfortunately your `jsonObject` is statically typed as a `JsValue`, not a `JsObject`. You can get around this in a couple of ways. The first is to use `as`:

```
 scala> jsonObject.as[JsObject] + ("c" -> Json.toJson(3))
 res0: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

With `as` you're essentially downcasting—you're telling the compiler, "you only know that this is a `JsValue`, but believe me, it's also a `JsObject`". This is safe in this case, but it's not a good idea. A more principled approach is to use the `OWrites` directly:

```
scala> val jsonObject = classAWrites.writes(classAObject)
jsonObject: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"a":1,"b":2}

scala> jsonObject + ("c" -> Json.toJson(3))
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

Maybe someday the `Json` object will have a `toJsonObject` method that will require a `OWrites` instance and this overly explicit approach won't be necessary.

Comment: Per signature, `Writes.writes` returns `JsValue`, so I don't understand how you can get rid of upcasting (not in the REPL).

Comment: Tvaroh is right, it return JsValue as far as I can see

Comment: @elmalto Try it out—`classAWrites` will be statically typed as `OWrites[ClassA]` (in both Play 2.2 and 2.3 and on 2.10 and 2.11). This is due to "underspecified but intended" behavior of Scala's macros (see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13669974/334519) for details).

Comment: Skipping the definition for the class and writer for brevity, but this is what the repl gives me:
`scala> SessionCreatorWriter.writes(s)`
`res2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue`

Comment: @elmalto If you define a `Writes` instance you'll get `JsValue`, but if you define an `OWrites` instance—either manually or using the `Json.writes` macro, which is what the OP is doing—you'll get a `JsObject`.

Comment: @TravisBrown maybe I should've posted it then:
`implicit val SessionCreatorWriter = Json.writes[SessionCreator]`
`val s = SessionCreator("User1",None,None,None,1,None,None)`
`SessionCreatorWriter.writes(s)` and I get a JsValue

Comment: There's actually no need for the paranthesis. This works: `jsobj +  "key" -> entity.key`

Comment: @Wrench That does something completely different. `+` and `-` have the same precedence, so the parentheses are definitely necessary.

Comment: Why is `Json.toJson(3)` needed in this scenario. Even though it's not needed when doing `Json.obj("a" -> 3)` ??

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution myself. In fact the JsValue, which is the return type of Json.toJson has no such method, but the JsObject (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsObject) does, so the solution is:

```
val jsonObject = Json.toJson(classAObject).as[JsObject]
jsonObject + ("c", JsNumber(3))
```

I hope someone will find this useful :)

Answer (score -1):

simpler way is to use argoanut (http://argonaut.io/)

```
var jField : Json.JsonField = "myfield" //Json.JsonField is of type String
obj1.asJson.->:(jField, obj2.asJson)  // adds a field to obj1.asJson
```

here `obj1.asJson` creates a JSON object
and `obj2` is the object to be added to the json created by `obj1.asJson`