# Adding fields/values to an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to figure out a way to add field names and values to an object.

for example I hav ethe following...

```
$scope.product = {
        "Requirements": [
            {
                "OriginPostcode": '',
                "BearerSize": 100,
                "BandwidthRequired": 10
            }
        ]
   }
```

And I want to add two more names and values...

```
 "Term": 36,
 "Quantity": 1
```

I know the push() function is for arrays. What do you uses for objects?

Many thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855710/play-framework-add-a-field-to-json-object

Comment: That's a JavaScript object. There's no JSON there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use baces passing index like an array:

```
  $scope.product["Requirements"][0]["Term"] = 36
  $scope.product["Requirements"][0]["Quantity"] = 1
```

you can also do in this way

```
   $scope.product["Requirements"][0].Term = 36
   $scope.product["Requirements"][0].Quantity = 1
```

and also...

```
   $scope.product.Requirements[0].Term = 36
   $scope.product.Requirements[0].Quantity = 1
```

What do you need to understand is how to go through a javascript object using braces [] or point . Take a look at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp)

Comment: thank you - the third option worked for me