# typescript parameter to an object declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript, want to convert the following values to an object so that I may reuse them in the form of an object variable.

```
 abc.create ( param1, {
            main: this.ODDD,
            filter: this.RLL
        }, param3)
```

I'm trying to declare a variable 'param2' so that I may use the second parameter which is of type Object so that I may use it at other places. I'm trying to do it like this but can't work out.

```
 var param2: Object = {
        main: string, 
        filter: string
    };
```

but it doesn't allow me to create this or assign values, the error is: 
"string only refers to a type but it is used as a value here".

Have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729643/typescript-array-of-key-value-pairs-declaration) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434570/adding-fields-values-to-an-object) but didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `Object.assign(target, param1, ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create interfaces to achieve the same

```
interface Param {
     main: string,
     filter: string, 
}

let abc = {
   create (param1, param2: Param, param3) {
        //your code
   } 
}

let param2: Param = <Param>{
  main: "string content",
  filter: "string content2"
}

abc.create(param1, param2, param3);
```

Comment: declaring an interface didn't work for me as I wanted to declare a variable first and assign the value later. I changed that to class and it worked:
let param2: Param = new Param();
param2.main = "abc";
param2.filter = "anything";