# Create a json object and adding new key, value pairs to it

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I've a scala Map which is of form `<String, Any>`. My objective is to iterate over all the key of the map and create a new json object which consists of all these `k,v` pairs. I'm using play framework for the json library.

I tried this:

```
var out  = JsNull
for (str <- inp) {
    out = out.as[JsObject] + (str -> Json.toJson(inp(str)))
}
```

However Json.toJson returns a JsonNode whereas it is expecting a JsValue. I've looked at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855710/play-framework-add-a-field-to-json-object) for adding new items.

*Question 1:* How do I convert JsonNode to JsValue

*Question 2:* This is a bad implementation in scala. I'm using var. How do I convert the same logic so that I use a val. I'm particularly new to functional programming, so have a tough time thinking away from the usual iterative loops.

Comment: why don't you convert the Map to json with Json.toJson instead of iterating on it ? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaJson

Comment: It amazes me how much people don't understand how serialization of JSON works with GSON, Play etc etc. I see a question like this almost every time I get on SO. Le sigh....