# Add key/value to existing JsValue in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to figure out how I would add a key/value to a JsValue. In JavaScript you might do something like `SomeObject.newKey = newValue`. Here's my real use case:

```
  def doAccountUpdate(account: db.models.Account, config: JsObject, job: JsValue) : JsValue = {
    val passwordParam = (job \ "params" \ "password")
    if (passwordParam.toOption.isDefined) {
      val password = (job \ "params" \ "password").get.as[String]
      val encrypted_password = Auth.passwordEncrypt(password)
      // ADD `encrypted_password`'s value TO `job \ params` so its `job \ params \ encryptedPassword`
    }

    Account.update(account, config, job)
  }
```

`Account.update` actually updates the DB so in my `doAccountUpdate` i'm prepping the data. One of those items I need to prep is password by encrypting it before passing it to `Account.update`. How do I do this?

EDIT

To explain why the question this is marked a duplicate of doesn't work for me is this is their example:

```
jsonObject.as[JsObject] + ("c" -> Json.toJson(3))
```

If I duplicate that in my code it would look like this:

```
updateJob = job.as[JsObject] + ("encryptedPassword" -> Json.toJson(encrypted_password))
```

but that outputs:

```
{
    "id":"...",
    "params": {
        "password":"Programmer2!"
    },
    "encryptedPassword":"$2a$10$EHnJHXh1sTORxliPocWfDuHnlRzu1YwG.kyBee.u85apCXTuLij.y"
}
```

Note how `encryptedPassword` isn't in `params`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play Framework - add a field to JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855710/play-framework-add-a-field-to-json-object)

Comment: @danielnixon updated to explain why it's not quite the same in my case. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Maybe take a look at cases 4 and 5 here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @danielnixon suggests, you can use JSON transformers for this. Here is an example:

```
val encryptPassword: Reads[JsObject] = (__ \ "params").json.update(
  (__ \ "password").read[String].flatMap(pw =>
    (__ \ "encryptedPassword").json.put(JsString(Auth.passwordEncrypt(pw)))
  )
)
```

This says we will:

1. update the `params` object
2. read the existing password
3. put a new `encryptedPassword` branch in the `params` object

When you apply that with `job.transform(encryptPassword)` you'll get a `JsResult` that, if the params object exists and has a `password` field with a string value, will be `JsSuccess` - otherwise you'll get `JsError`. You can handle that with something like the following:

```
def doAccountUpdate(account: db.models.Account, config: JsObject, job: JsValue) : JsValue = {
  job.transform(encryptPassword) match {
    case JsSuccess(newJob, _) => Account.update(account, config, newJob)
    case JsError(errors) => sys.error("No password supplied!")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was super helpful!